# A notion of polygon centrality meeting certain conditions

Tags: geometry

Is anybody aware of a definition of the center of a polygon that meets each of the following criteria?

1. For a regular polygon with at least 5 sides, it is the point equidistant from all vertices.
2. For a square, either the whole square meets the definition or no points in the square do.
3. For an equilateral triangle, no point in the triangle meets the definition.

I've observed a point that appears to be roughly in the center of polygons (regular or otherwise) but doesn't coincide with any definition of polygon centrality that I can find, and has the aforementioned weird behavior on squares and triangles.

This point I'm looking for gives the maximal Voronoi region of any generator point placed within the polygon, the vertices of which are other generator points. I've observed this behavior by implementing an algorithm in *Maximizing a Voronoi region: the convex case* by Dehne, Klein, and Seidel (2005). Getting any analytical insight on this point proves very challenging, so I'm essentially fishing here to see if it could, by chance, happen to coincide with a preexisting notion of centrality.

Comment: In case 1, is there necessarily a point equidistant from all 5 vertices?

Comment: If it's regular, yes... right? For an irregular polygon, I can't say anything too definitive. For one that's relatively regular (i.e. the vertices are not perturbed too far from being a regular polygon), the point appears intuitively at the center (but doesn't coincide with the centroid, or any other centrality definition I can find). For polygons that are more irregular still, it appears that there's no such point within the polygon. I omitted these extra details given how hand-wavy they are! @coffeemath Have I answered your question?

Comment: How intricate would it be for you to include in your question some details about how your "point" is calculated for a given polygon? That might increase the chances someone would recognize it as a case of something...

Comment: @coffeemath Good point. Added.